# Java, removing duplicate output from separate lines generated by nested for loops

Tags: java

I am new to java, and I have this program that takes a number between 1 and 10 from a user and displays the multiplication table for that number. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //importing the scanner library

public class question3 {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");
    int userNumber = keyb.nextInt();

    while (userNumber <= 0 || userNumber >= 10){
      System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");
      userNumber = keyb.nextInt();
    }
    keyb.close();

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= userNumber; counter++){
      System.out.print(counter + "\t");
      for (int number = 2; number <= userNumber; number++){
        System.out.print((counter * number) + "\t");
      }
      System.out.println(" ");
    }
  }
}
```

So if the user enters 4, the output will look like:

```
1    2    3    4
2    4    6    8
3    6    9    12
4    8    12   16
```

This works. I need to take the multiplication table and remove any duplicate numbers. So if the user enters 4, the desired output will look like:

```
1    2    3   4
     4    6   8
          9   12
              16
```

How can I remove the duplicate output when it only exists in the for loop print statements?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't "remove" stuff that you already printed to the console. You just need to change your code to not print it in the first place.

Comment: There's a clear pattern in the desired result.

Comment: Right, so I'm assuming another nested for loop would work here, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: No, you don't need another loop. Just a conditional check inside your loop to check wether to print the number or blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra `List<Integer>` to check the condition only: ***(Just need to align the space(DIY)***)

```
public class question3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");
    int userNumber = keyb.nextInt();

    while (userNumber <= 0 || userNumber >= 10) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");
        userNumber = keyb.nextInt();
    }
    keyb.close();

    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= userNumber; counter++) {
        if (!arr.contains(counter)) {
            System.out.print(counter + "\t");
            arr.add(counter);
        } else
            System.out.println("\t");
        for (int number = 2; number <= userNumber; number++) {
            if (!arr.contains((counter * number))) {
                System.out.print((counter * number) + "\t");
                arr.add((counter * number));
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\t");
    }
}
```

}

***EDIT:***
Also utilize `do-while` loop here to avoid duplicate code to ask input like

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer between 1 and 10: ");
            int userNumber = keyb.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set<Integer> generatedNumbers = new HashSet<>();

    for(int counter = 1; counter <= userNumber; counter+=1)
    {
        System.out.print((generatedNumbers.contains(counter) ? "" : counter) + "\t");
        generatedNumbers.add(counter);

        for(int number = 2; number <= userNumber; number+=1)
        {
            int product = number * counter;
            System.out.print((generatedNumbers.contains(product) ? "" : product) + "\t");
            generatedNumbers.add(product);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```